# Could not resolve org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I download the latest tensorflow lite demo, show it:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': 
Could not resolve org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you add `jcenter()` ?

Comment: yes, i have added jcenter().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i open it again, I can built it successfully. Maybe because network-wall in china. i missed some files. i downloaded it in path: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.
demo in path: tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo/

I like this demo, it works well.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.12.0'
```

more information, please visit https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite/maven-metadata.xml

Answer (score 2):

The previous nightly build was broken due to the Jcenter updates. Please refer to the [new nightly build](https://bintray.com/google/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite):

```
org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 2):

**kindly replace this dependency**
**from**

```
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'
```

**to**

```
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.12.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Project-level `build.gradle` file - make sure you have this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { // repo for TFLite snapshot
            name 'ossrh-snapshot'
            url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
    }
}
```

Adding that last part with the `ossrh-snapshot` fixed it for me.

Answer (score -4):

close AndroidStudio totally, then start AndroidStudio, no problem any more!

Comment: reopening project does works, probably connection problem or a bug in the download request