# Tensorflow image classification Android example fails to build

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I cloned the https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android this link to try image classification example but it fails to build.

I tried the suggestion listed in below link but that didn't help.

[Could not resolve org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959328/could-not-resolve-org-tensorflowtensorflow-lite0-0-0-nightly)

It is failing to resolve

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly'
```

I am getting below error in **android studio 3.4.2**:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

Comment: have you got `jcenter()` as a repository in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: @Blundell yes, it is already part of that. You can also verify that by visiting the github link. I think it should build without me modifying anything right? What is the point of giving example when it even fails to build?

Answer (score 0):

Change your dependencies like this:

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
// The GPU delegate library is optional. Depend on it as needed.
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
```

Answer (score 0):

For Tensorflow lite GPU you have to use below dependency inside app build.gradle file:

`implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'`

and this at project build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {     // should be already there
    mavenCentral  // should be already there
    maven {       // add this repo to use snapshots
      name 'ossrh-snapshot'
      url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
    }
}
```

You can find more info [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android#use_the_tensorflow_lite_aar_from_mavencentral)